# Recurrence Relation for the following code?

Tags: algorithm, b-tree, recurrence

[image]

What is the recurrence relation of the above algorithm? a step-by-step walkthrough would be appreciated.

Comment: That's incomplete information to give a recurrence relation. What are x.c?

Comment: x.n = number of keys in node ;
x.key = value of key ;
x.leaf = boolean(true if leaf) ;
x.c = child node ;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your algorithm comprise for following steps :

1. Initially it makes a linear search for the key, since it searches for all the elements it will add a complexity of -----> theta(n)
2. If it finds the key, it returns
3. Else, it recurses by passing it's child ------> T(child)

So, overall complexity : 
T(n) = T(n+1) + theta(n) ,

where T(n+1) will be the complexity for child node